# Strange single quote escaping

Tags: javascript, escaping

```
var a = "Test \'"
> undefined
var b = "Test '"
> undefined
a === b
> true
a
> "Test '"
```

[image]

Yep. I know that both stings are equal ( a show it in example code ) - the question is **why**

Why escaping sing quote produce such strange result? Explain please.

Thx in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know that both stings are equal ( a show it in example code ) - the question is **why**

The escape character is **never** part of the string *value*. It's only used by the parser to determine the string value.

The spec explains [how escape sequences are evaluated](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-static-semantics-sv):

[image]

You can see that escape sequences in double quoted strings (`DoubleStringCharacter`) is evaluated exactly the same as escape sequences in single quoted strings (`SingleStringCharacter`). Both evaluate `\ EscapeSequence`.

Comment: Why it parse \ as escaping if I use double quotes ?

Comment: Because \ is always the escape character. It doesn't matter whether you use single quotes or double quotes.

Answer (score 3):

The backslash in the string is used to escape the following character. When using single quote inside a double-quoted string, the single quote is not needed to be escaped.

Thus,

```
"Test \'s" === "Test 's"
'Test\"s'  === 'Test"s'
```

Consider a case where you want to include both single quotes and double quotes in string. In this case, there should be some way to escape the inner quotes otherwise compiler will throw an error at invalid string. By using backslash `\`, the following character can be escaped and it'll be considered as normal literal instead of it's special meaning in the context.

```
"He said, \"My name is something, I stay at my uncle's house.\""
```

Comment: I know it. it described in my question. The question is 'WHY?'

Comment: @VasiliyVanchuk I've added explanation

Comment: Why it parse \ as escaping for sing quote if I use double quotes ?

Comment: @VasiliyVanchuk As I already said, \ is escaping anything that follows it, there is no need to escape single quote inside double quote. If you want backslash in the string you've to escape the backslash too. `"Test \\' abc"`.

Comment: If the is no need - why it parse \' like esxaping?

Comment: @VasiliyVanchuk The backslash **don't** care if the following char. need to be escaped or not, it just do it, since that's what it is said to do.

Answer (score 3):

They are equal:

```
"Test '".length // 6
"Test \'".length // 6
```

The following table lists the special characters that you can use in JavaScript strings: `\0 \b \f \n \r \t \v \' \" \\ \XXX \xXX \uXXXX \u{XXXXX}`

For characters not listed in the table, a preceding backslash is ignored, but this usage is deprecated and should be avoided.

**Resume:**

JavaScript converts the string `"Test \'"` to `"Test '"` and then compares with the other `"Test '"` string.

Comment: I know it. it described in my question. The question is 'WHY?'

Comment: Actually In JavaScript `\'` is the same as `'`. Backslash just uses for escaping special characters which listed in my question in strings.

Comment: Why it parse \ as escaping if I use double quotes ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like the interpreter is automatically escaping out the single quote ' due to the presence of the double quote " So it sees the string starts with " and accepts anything in the text.

It expects \ to be an escape character so \' will produce just '
It also expects " to terminate the string so will allow ' in the string body just the same. Thus in memory, both strings will be

```
Test "
```

This is just my guess, but it seems the most reasonable to me. a===b is true because both strings are actually the same. I don't know how javascript works in the background but in most programming languages, a and b would actually both be pointing to the same object in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Your escaping is useless, so the interpretor ignore it.

```
var a = "Test \'"
var b = "Test '"

a
> "Test '"
b
> "Test '"
```

if you write:

```
var a = "\a";
a
> "a"
```

As i said, un unexpected excaping is just ignored.

Comment: I know it. it described in my question. The question is 'WHY?'