# Typescript strange escape character behavior

Tags: typescript

Query is similar to the one mentioned [in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37028780/strange-single-quote-escaping)

New to typescript and front end dev. Using Angular form to take input from user which may contain regex.

Example:

this.expressions is actually a input from form multiple expressions can be passed seperated by new line character.

```
this.rewrite_object = []
this.expressions = "s|.*|{{ date | replace('-', '') }}\"/apps/data/{{ date | replace('-', '/') }}"
this.rewrite_array = this.expressions.split('\n')
console.log("******************Print after split******************")
console.log(this.rewrite_array)
if (this.rewrite_array.length > 0) {
   for(var i = 0;i<this.rewrite_array.length;i++) { 
      if (this.rewrite_array[i]) {
        console.log("******************Print before adding to array******************")
        console.log(this.rewrite_array[i])
        this.rewrite_object.push({ "expression": this.rewrite_array[i] });
        console.log("******************Print rewrite object******************")
        console.log(this.rewrite_object)
      }
   }
}
```

This is what I get in output. escape character vanish.

```
******************Print after split******************                                                                                       
[                                                                                                                                           
  `s|.*|{{ date | replace('-', '') }}"/apps/data/{{ date | replace('-', '/') }}`                                                            
]                                                                                                                                           
******************Print before adding to array******************                                                                            
s|.*|{{ date | replace('-', '') }}"/apps/data/{{ date | replace('-', '/') }}                                                                
******************Print rewrite object******************                                                                                    
[                                                                                                                                           
  {                                                                                                                                         
    expression: `s|.*|{{ date | replace('-', '') }}"/apps/data/{{ date | replace('-', '/') }}`                                              
  }                                                                                                                                         
]
```

Thought of escaping escape character itself by using \ but this fails with error during compilation.

```
test.ts:2:70 - error TS1136: Property assignment expected.                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                            
2 this.expressions = "s|.*|{{ date | replace('-', '') }}\\"/apps/data/{{ date | replace('-', '/') }}"                                       
                                                                       ~                                                                    
                                                                                                                                            
test.ts:2:98 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.                                                                             
                                                                                                                                            
2 this.expressions = "s|.*|{{ date | replace('-', '') }}\\"/apps/data/{{ date | replace('-', '/') }}"                                       
                                                                                                   ~                                        
                                                                                                                                            
test.ts:2:100 - error TS1002: Unterminated string literal.                                                                                  

2 this.expressions = "s|.*|{{ date | replace('-', '') }}\\"/apps/data/{{ date | replace('-', '/') }}"
                                                                                                     


Found 3 errors.
```

How can we make " work with typescript as it's. I need to save this information in DB after taking as input from customer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the backslash but *still also escape the double quote*: to receive a `\"` in the final string you have to write `\\\"` within your doubl-quoted string.

The first `\` will escape the second one giving you one literal `\` in the resulting string. The third `\` escapes the double quote so it will be included in the resulting string and not terminate your string.

```js
this.expressions = "s|.*|{{ date | replace('-', '') }}\\\"/apps/data/{{ date | replace('-', '/') }}"
```

Comment: Tried this expression. it will become.  
~~~
******************Print after split******************
[
  `s|.*|{{ date | replace('-', '') }}\\"/apps/data/{{ date | replace('-', '/') }}`
]
******************Print before adding to array******************
s|.*|{{ date | replace('-', '') }}\"/apps/data/{{ date | replace('-', '/') }}
******************Print rewrite object******************
[
  {
    expression: `s|.*|{{ date | replace('-', '') }}\\"/apps/data/{{ date | replace('-', '/') }}`
  }
]
~~~

Comment: surprisngly this become in DB after post.. 6 backslashes 
`
    name    |                                               rewrites                                                
------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 transfer18 | [{"expression": "s|.*|{{ date | replace('-', '') }}\\\\\"/apps/data/{{ date | replace('-', '/') }}"}]
(1 row)
`